# How to create sender.tag UIButton in another function?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of answers and an array of buttons. When I click on a particular button, with the help of a sender.tag, I have an index change. I also need to do in `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` so that the answer is set by the index and the result will go to another screen.

When i tried to create sender.tag i have error

> Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'tag'

```
@IBAction func answerPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let index = sender.tag
    let currentAnswer = currentQuestions?.answers[index]

    if currentAnswer!.type != .next {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: sender)
    } else {
        currentQuestions = currentAnswer!.nextQuestion
        updateTittles(currentQuestions)
    }
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let index = sender.tag
    let currentType = currentQuestions?.answers[index].type

    let resultViewController = segue.destination as! ResultViewController
    resultViewController.type = currentType

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sender` in this case for the prepare for segue function is not necessarily a `UIButton`, it's whatever initiated the segue. You could check to see if it's a button by trying to cast it to one as follows:

```
if let button = sender as? UIButton {
    index = button.tag
}
```

What you could also do is in the `answerPressed` function instead of performing a segue you could instantiate the `ResultViewController` yourself there and then push to it. Because when you're in this function you know that the sender is a `UIButton` and it should have a tag.

Answer (score 2):

As *Any*thing can be the type of `sender` the parameter is declared as `Any`

First check for the `identifier` of the segue, on success force downcast the `sender` parameter to `UIButton`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard segue.identifier == "segue" else { return }
    let button = sender as! UIButton
    let currentType = currentQuestions?.answers[button.tag].type
    let resultViewController = segue.destination as! ResultViewController
    resultViewController.type = currentType

}
```

But it's not necessary to pass the entire `UIButton` instance, the tag/index is sufficient, or – even more efficient – pass `currentAnswer.type`

```
@IBAction func answerPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let index = sender.tag
    let currentAnswer = currentQuestions?.answers[index]

    if currentAnswer!.type != .next {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: index)
    } else {
        currentQuestions = currentAnswer!.nextQuestion
        updateTittles(currentQuestions)
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard segue.identifier == "segue" else { return }
    let index = sender as! Int
    let currentType = currentQuestions?.answers[index].type
    let resultViewController = segue.destination as! ResultViewController
    resultViewController.type = currentType
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'tag'

Means that `Any` object has no indeed a `tag` property. You know your `sender` is a `UIButton`, so why not **CAST** that `sender` of `prepareForSegue` to a `UIButton` object, like so?

`guard let buttonSender = sender as? UIButton else { return }`